# OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.Model, but this is no longer supported in openai\>=1.0.0"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, configuration, openai-api

Using Visual Studio Code and PyCharm, after install openai (pip install openai) a strange error is bugging me - please help.

If for example I write:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

lista_de_modelos = openai.Model.list()
print(lista_de_modelos)
```

it fails and I get an this error:

```
PS C:\\proyectoVS_Python\> & "C:/Users/kitkatuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe" "c:/proyectoVS_Python/import os.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\proyectoVS_Python\\import os.py", line 5, in \<module\>
lista_de_modelos = openai.Model.list()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\kitkatuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai_utils_proxy.py", line 22, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.__get_proxied__(), attr)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\kitkatuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai_utils_proxy.py", line 43, in __get_proxied__  
return self.__load__()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\kitkatuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\lib_old_api.py", line 33, in __load__
raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self.\_symbol)
openai.lib.\_old_api.APIRemovedInV1:

You tried to access openai.Model, but this is no longer supported in openai\>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

PS C:\\proyectoVS_Python\>
```

What I´m doing wrong? why I can't access openAI, I've try several keys, the same program and process to install works well with other friends. Using Pycharm shows similar. I'm used several programs to try but always similar response! I don't find a solution or similar problems! I'm really confused!Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

**The method name you're trying to use doesn't work with the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer.**

The old SDK (i.e., version `0.28`) works with the following method name:

```
client.Model.list
```

The new SDK (i.e., version `1.0.0` or newer) works with the following method name:

```
client.models.list
```

*Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., `client.Models.list` will not work with the new SDK version).*

#### Solution

Try this:

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

client.models.list()
```

Comment: You're right with case-sensitive ... Fast typing sorry. I've created an .env file to store the key in other versions too, etc. But the solution is thanks to line: client = OpenAI().  Merci

Comment: @JoséAlonso You're welcome. :)